# flexigrid, load data based on the page number passed in the query string ( example.com?page_no = 2 )

Tags: jquery, flexigrid

I have data of 20 rows, initiated as rows per page as 10, show in Flexigrid I can navigate to second page via given paging buttons in the Flexigrid.

My scenario is if the user want to edit the record displayed in the second page, he will click the edit button in that row, he will be redirected to the form, once the data is saved, user must see the same row, which is in the second page in flexigrid.

How to load the second page directly in flexigrid?

Comment: Please mark answer as "Accept" if it worked for you.. So that other users might as well make use..

Answer (score 1):

after the delete action, reload the flex. While reloading pass the page number to the newp. this should solve it.

I use this method to load 1st page after every refresh. This should work.

$('#MyFlex') .flexOptions({ url: urlAction, newp: 2 }).flexReload();